# The RedisTemplate and GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer are not serializing correctly

Tags: java, json, jackson

When I use the GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer from Jackson for serialization, it fails to convert properly. Here is the relevant code:

```java
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    // 如果您的 JacksonObjectMapper 是在其他地方定义的 @Bean，您可以通过 @Autowired 注入
    private final JacksonObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper;

    public RedisConfig(JacksonObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper) {
        this.jacksonObjectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(factory);

        // 使用 StringRedisSerializer 来序列化和反序列化 redis 的 key 值
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

        // 使用 StringRedisSerializer 来序列化和反序列化 redis 的 hash 的 key 值
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

        // 使用 GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer 来序列化和反序列化 redis 的 value 值
        GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer genericSerializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(jacksonObjectMapper);
        template.setValueSerializer(genericSerializer);

        // 使用 GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer 来序列化和反序列化 redis 的 hash 的 value 值
        template.setHashValueSerializer(genericSerializer);

        return template;
    }

    private static GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer createJsonRedisSerializer() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Jackson 2.10+ 的配置方式
        objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(
                objectMapper.getPolymorphicTypeValidator(),
                ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL,
                JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY
        );

        // 配置自定义的null值处理
        DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl sp = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();
        sp.setNullValueSerializer(new MyNullValueSerializer());
        objectMapper.setSerializerProvider(sp);

        return new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper);
    }

    // 其他配置和@Bean方法...
}

// 自定义null值序列化器
class MyNullValueSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(""); // 或者任何其他的null值表示
    }

}
```

I expect the information cached in Redis to have an additional class field:

```json
{
  "@class": "com.example.Person",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 30
}
```

However, in reality, it is not present:

```json
{
  "@class": "com.example.Person",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 30
}
```

Unable to serialize properly.I have also added the configuration to enable default typing in the text, but it seems to have no effect.